# Wordpress, "set names 'utf'8'" before posts query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, encoding, character-encoding

I'm having a problem with Wordpress migration, related to MySQL database.
I'm facing a charset encoding problem, so in the new hosting the letters with an accent, like "à", "è" are shown as a question mark.

I know from other projects that if, before a query I make this one

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

the errors disappears.
I also tested it in a custom php page, trying to get a post content.

So, there is a way to tell wordpress to do this query before every post query?!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just solved by changing the database charset from latin_swedisc_ci to `utf_8_general_ci` and by editing the `wp-config.php` file, changing this row from
`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');`
 to
`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('posts_fields', 'my_posts_fields');

function my_posts_fields( $fields, &$wp_query ) {
    $fields = "SET NAMES 'utf8'; " . $fields;
}
```

This will adjust the SELECT clause of the main query so that instead of SELECT it becomes SET NAMES utf-8; SELECT

Comment: Thanks MirzaP, I didn't try this solution because I've found in the meantime another solution, but it sound like your solution could have even worked

Comment: This is way overcomplicating things. Of course Wordpress can handle the database connection encoding correctly without needing to add query hacks in a filter.